# When is an installation/question about tool a valid question?

Tags: support

I know that most of the questions are valid when it comes to software installation, such as:

[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

[Windows 7 SDK installation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901279/windows-7-sdk-installation-failure)

However this question is about where to find a software:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314078/where-can-i-find-pws-installer/25314195#25314195

I did answer it, but I am not so sure whether the question is valid or not.

**How can I establish a baseline for these kind of questions?**

Comment: They are completely different.  Not sure why you can't see that.  Go read through the different close reasons.  You'll find one of the three should be closed.

Comment: @Will What makes me confused is because when you ask for something like *"How to install X"* it seems to me that you are also asking for finding a tool or a resource/tutorial which is the same "flag" for me (as I can't cast close votes here).

Comment: Big difference between how to install something and where to download it.  Installation implies that you already have, or know where to get, it.  If a question asks both, the usual solution is to close or edit out the link beg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asking where to find an installer is off-topic. That information is subject to being out of date very quickly, and is better maintained on a project site than here. We shouldn't be a substitute for Google.

---

To address your other two examples, **How to install pip on windows?** wasn't a great question to begin with, but it wasn't just asking where to download an installer. I think a really great, detailed answer saved this question. **Windows 7 SDK installation failure** is better. It tells us what's been tried and even gives an error message.

Comment: The JSTL folks have included download/installation info in [their tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) for a while now, which is an interesting solution to keeping this up-to-date: they're still able to answer questions on the topic, by referring them to the wiki without needing to post potentially-brittle information all over the place. Not appropriate in every situation of course.

Comment: @Shog9 That's a nice tag wiki. Also, that's a good solution for projects of that size, and is definitely preferable to asking a new question every time something is moved on/disappears from SourceForge, GitHub, etc.