# Is this a good self-answered question or is there a better approach?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, self-answer

I intended to write a question regarding the installation of Anaconda on CentOS 8 and eventually found the answer.

In order to support the community, as the procedure may help, took the time to write the question and post an answer documented with screen captures, and updated the question, with the following in the question ([Install Anaconda on CentOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64262446)):

> This QnA is meant to be an helpful user-guide on installing Anaconda
> on CentOS 8.
>
> Please note that this post is not meant to be a replacement for the
> documentation, so please read that if you need!

It seems to be that the question was not well received by some users. One user voted to close, another user suggests to write that under [Anaconda's tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/anaconda/info).

Considering that the content may be helpful, what should be the best approach in this case?

The question was closed with the following justification:

> This question does not appear to be about programming within the
> scope defined in the help center.

I disagree, as it covers "software tools commonly used by programmers, and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

I also don't see it fit any of the 8 points mentioned in "[Don't Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)" part of the help-center , but I am open to hear about which one's do you think it fit.

Comment: can you post a specific problem you encountered while attempting to install anaconda on centos8?  then your answer would address that specific problem.

Comment: It is ok to self-answer your question or that you even create a question in order to self-answer it right away, but the question and the answer still must follow the rules of this site. The question text currently does not. You _must_ edit it to actually ask a question there.

Comment: Just because something is useful, does not mean it is on topic. It would be useful to be able to know how to convince my client to throw away their 15 year old code and rewrite it using modern techniques and technology, but it would be off topic on Stack Overflow. Installation tutorials (no matter how well dressed) are simply not something that Stack Overflow was built to support. Post it on your blog, on Medium; on Dev.to; on some other site, and I'm sure people will appreciate it.

Comment: Questions on SO are to ask one specific question. The example you link to "lacks focus" in that regard in that it asks seven unrelated questions including at least one that is opinion. Your multiple questions are related in that regard. The one remaining problem is that your "question" is not a question at all but a guide or tutorial. SO is for questions with answers to specific issues.

Comment: The topics are on the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: That is not what I had in mind.  I was thinking of something like... "when I tried to install, I got the foobar error.  how do I fix it?"

Comment: I am a bit baffled why you feel the question would be suitable. The first iteration asked no question at all, making it unanswerable by definition. The next iteration asked three, then five questions, making it text-book "needs focus". Even then, each individual answer is extremely broad and "needs details". Can you clarify why you think the question as is would be a good fit for SO?

Comment: Focus on only 1 question. You may even split up into three self-answered questions. Or make the answer broad adding related question/answers, but the question should be specific and only one, even if it covers related issues.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi TheMaster the question is "how to install Anaconda on CentOS 8". I broke it down to a couple more points to help others see the relevance.

Comment: Appearances are important. I think both Q1 and Q2 can  be removed. Q3 should be enough. You can explain the issue, but do not make it look like 3 separate questions. That being said, I disagree with the current close reason and vtr.

Comment: I would still rephrase the second para to something like "I tried to install with and without GUI, But I'm running into various errors like {example errors}. I'm also concerned about the security of the file downloaded. How to proceed?" -something like that. Make it a actual question. Userguide part can be added at last as some sort of bottomline note.

Comment: IMO the general issue is that the question very obviously does not serve to solve a real problem. "How to install Anaconda 3 on CentOS 8?" is not a problem, it is a task that should be solved by reading the documentation – which the question even links to. Downloading from the internet, being concerned about security, are not problems. What went wrong? Why do you need this with and without GUI? What parts of the documentation did you fail to understand? What are these vague security concerns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The justification for the topicality of the question is that it's about the installation of a programming tool (Anaconda).

There are more than one question ([this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268768/when-is-an-installation-question-about-tool-a-valid-question), [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338203/can-i-ask-questions-about-installation-in-so) or [this other one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378140/why-was-a-question-about-installing-netbeans-closed-for-seeking-recommendations?rq=1), for example; I'm sure there are loads more if one searches) here on meta dealing with this kind of post, and they are generally considered on-topic.

That being said, **I don't particularly like these questions**. They are generally *broadish*, covering many userland problems that are not specific to developers (e.g. "how to download a file", "how to decompress an archive", "how to verify a file hash").

So, while they are considered on-topic by many, and nowadays I don't vote to close them, I don't consider them particularly useful additions to the repository and **vote** accordingly. These questions prompt answers that are tutorial-like posts that are better hosted elsewhere, IMO.

Additionally, your edit with numerous bullet-points expose the weakness of the question, showing how the question is actually composed of many smaller non-developer issues. The on-topic question would be "how to install Anaconda v.X on CentOS 8", without all the other additional bullet-points.

Still a poor question, but at least on-topic.

Comment: Thank you @yivi, it is also not a type of questions that I ask (it is my first one like this). Considering that it is "On-Topic", why is the question closed with the justification of not being on topic?

Comment: Because other users thought differently. Not everybody agrees on everything. The rules exist, but they are interpreted by humans. I'm just a monkey so I'm more more objective, but humans are less reliable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here as I see it: first, it contains multiple questions. Second, it doesn't ask a specific question (just "how do I do *x*?"), so it reads a little more like a tutorial than a SO Q&A.

Keep in mind that, even if you're writing a self-answer, the question itself is still subject to the same quality standards as an "ordinary" question is. This helps to give adequate context to the answer so that people can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad self-answered question *because there is no question*.

---

A good self-answered question is a good question which just happens to be self-answered. That means the question by itself should raise a clear, answerable issue about a programming related topic. The question *must* be well-defined and answerable *without* the self-answer.

So far, the question has failed to do this in every revision. It either contained [no question at all](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64262446/1), a [rehash of the self-answer posed as multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64262446/3), and [finally some very broad concerns on security](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64262446/7). It is simply impossible to know which issues there are for downloading, installing and verification without the self-answer.

The real problem however is really that *there really is no question!* The question body links to the [installation instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) which already seems to answer everything, to the point that the self-answer even copies some parts of it.